# Access element of ndarray with shape=(dim,L,2)

Tags: python, list, function, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am currently working with numpy.ndarray. I initialize a multi-dimensional matrix :

`phi = np.zeros(dim_tuple(dim,L)+(2,))`

where dim_tuple(dim,L) return the tuple (L,L, ... ,L) with dim times L.

I would like to create a function taking as arguments:

- an array x of length dim
- a number N: 0 or 1

which will update the value of the element [x[0],x[1], ..., x[dim],N] of the matrix phi.

From now, I tried this:

`index = np.append(x,N)`

`phi[index]=new_value`

except that it does not works. In fact, I check that it returns this command:

`phi[[x[0],x[1],...,x[dim],N]] = new_value`

I tried to find an answer on the internet but I was not successful.

Thank you for your help !

Jérémie

Comment: Please add sample output. I would suggest maybe a 3 by 3 by 3 by 2.

Comment: Also I believe `dim_tuple(dim,L)` is just `(L,) * dim`

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) You are right with this remark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
phi[tuple(x) + (N,)] = new_value
```